# what is bazel-tensorflow inside tensorflow source folder?

Tags: tensorflow, eigen, eigen3

After building tensorflow, it generates some folders starting with bazel-*. And those folders are only soft links to other folders under /private/var/tmp on my Mac.

Now I want to change some code inside Eigen CXX11 library, and I only find them under bazel-tensorflow/external. My guess is these source files are generated at runtime. So where I can find the original source of Eigen and modify them?

Comment: I think that those bazel folders are from the bazel building process. Did you build from source by any chance?

Comment: Yes I built it from source. I want to change some logics inside Eigen library but fail to find the proper place. Under the original folder to which the bazel-tensorflow points, there's a README file which says ``This directory was generated by Blaze. Do not attempt to modify or delete any files in this directory.``

Comment: I can't help you with Eigen i'm afraid as I have no experience and don't want to lead you astray. I would suggest perhaps looking for original installation directory information from the Eigen devs. However be aware that it might require compiling from source to make any changes like that. It's not always as easy to just go and change a line of code without re-compiling a program. But In don't know Eigen so hopefully someone who does can come and help you

Comment: Thanks JCooke for your advice. You are a nice guy :)